# Storing and Retrieving a QFlags

Tags: qt4, bit-manipulation

I am planning to use `QFlags` for bit manipulation, I have a lot of bits to set(about 400), the problem I am facing now is if I convert `QFlags` to int I get 2 ^ 400 ,which I am unable to store it in a database, so my question if there is a method to store `QFlags` in a database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean an SQL database. You can make a lookup table containing values for each bit:

```
CREATE TABLE flags (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And then it's a simple many to many reference:

```
CREATE TABLE my_objects (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE object_flags (
    object_id INT NOT NULL,
    flag_id INT NOT NULL,
    value BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES my_object(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (flag_id) REFERENCES flags(id)
);
```

When you're saving a value to the database, it would look something like:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO object_flags (object_id, flag_id, value) VALUES(:oid, :fid, :flag_value)")
query.bind(":oid", my_object->id);
query.bind(":fid", id_of_flag_1);
query.bind(":flag_value", my_object->flags.testFlag(MyFlagsEnum::my_flag_1));
query.exec();
// etc for my_flag_2 and so on
```

And loading:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT oflags.value, fl.name FROM object_flags AS oflags INNER JOIN flags AS fl WHERE oflags.id = :oid");
query.bind(":oid", my_object->id);

while(query.next()) {
    bool flag = query.values(0).toBool();
    QString flag_name = query.values(1).toString();
    if(flag_name == "my_flag_1" && flag)
        my_object->flags |= MyFlagsEnum::my_flag_1;
    // etc for my_flag_2 and so on
}
```

That would be duplicated for each flag. I'm not familiar enough with Qt's metadata system to know if there is a more efficient way of getting at the flags data. Maybe you can leverage [X-Macros](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) to save some typing.

Comment: Should be OK there. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: But I don't understand how those tables can be used.

Comment: I added an example to my answer. Again, not tested, this is all off the top of my head.